# Assigning a list to multiple elements of a series

Tags: python, pandas

```py
import pandas as pd

series = pd.Series([[1, 2], [], [4, 5]])
series[[True, False, False]] = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

This fails because it thinks I want to map elements of the list to elements of the series, but I actually want to map the entire list to elements of the series, ie. I want a `pd.Series([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [], [4, 5]])`.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: There is no existing method to assign list values to multiple cells. This assignment creates ambiguity whether you want to assign this list to each cell or is it a list of (potentially different) values to be assigned across cells. The best you can do is to slice index and assign cell by cell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `numpy` to do that. When you use `series.values` or `series.to_numpy()`, Pandas returns a view so if you modify the `array`, it will modify the `Series`:

```
series = pd.Series([[1, 2], [], [4, 5]])

arr = series.to_numpy()  # or series.values
arr[np.where([True, False, False])] = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Output:

```
>>> arr
array([list([0, 0, 0, 0, 0]), list([]), list([4, 5])], dtype=object)

>>> series
0    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
1                 []
2             [4, 5]
dtype: object

>>> np.shares_memory(arr, series)
True
```

More about [`np.shares_memory`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.shares_memory.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Pandas is not designed to work with lists as items.

You can however loop over the items.

Taking advantage of lists mutability:

```
for l in series[[True, False, False]]:
    l[:] = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Or with [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
series[:] = [[0,0,0,0,0] if m else l 
             for l, m in zip(series, [True, False, False])]
```

Output:

```
0    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
1                 []
2             [4, 5]
dtype: object
```