# How to set multiple values in Pandas in column of dtype np.array?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I have a column of Numpy arrays in Pandas, something like:

```
   col1 col2    col3
0     1    a    None
1     2    b  [2, 4]
2     3    c    None
```

The `[2, 4]` is really `np.array([2, 4])`. Now I need to impute the missing values, and I have a list of arrays for that. For example:

```
vals_to_impute = [np.array([1, 2]), np.array([1, 4])]
```

I tried:

```
mask = col3.isna()
df.loc[mask, "col3"] = vals_to_impute
```

This results in error:

```
ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an ndarray
```

I tried converting to Numpy array, extracting column etc., nothing worked. Is it actually possible to set this in a vectorized operation, or do I have to do a manual loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to do it using pd.Series instead of list. I also had to input an index to this Series so that the insertion is correct. Maybe it can be done easier.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "col1": [1, 2, 3],
    "col2": ["a", "b", "c"],
    "col3": [None, np.array([2, 4]), None]
})

mask = df["col3"].isna()
vals_to_impute = pd.Series(
    [np.array([1, 2]), np.array([1, 4])],
    index=mask[mask].index
)

df.loc[mask, "col3"] = vals_to_impute

print(df)
```

Output:

```
   col1 col2    col3
0     1    a  [1, 2]
1     2    b  [2, 4]
2     3    c  [1, 4]
```

Comment: What I was missing was changing that index, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

One option using a short loop:

```
mask = df['col3'].isna()
vals = iter(vals_to_impute)

for idx in df.index[mask]:
    df.at[idx, 'col3'] = next(vals, None)
```

This can also be solved using an approach similar to that presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76641469/16343464), taking advantage of the shared memory when using the underlying numpy array:

```
mask = df['col3'].isna()
arr = df['col3'].to_numpy()
arr[np.where(mask)] = vals_to_impute
```

Modified DataFrame:

```
   col1 col2    col3
0     1    a  [1, 2]
1     2    b  [2, 4]
2     3    c  [1, 4]
```

Used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 3],
                   'col2': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
                   'col3': [None, np.array([2, 4]), None]})

vals_to_impute = [np.array([1, 2]), np.array([1, 4])]
```

Answer (score 1):

not sure where your problem actually is since you show only part of your code..

For me, this works just as expected:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [None, None, np.array([2, 2]), None, None]
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(data = data))

mask = df["data"].isna()
maskdata = [np.array([i, i]) for i in mask[mask].index]

df.loc[mask, "data"] = maskdata

# print(df)
# >>>     data
# >>> 0  [0, 0]
# >>> 1  [1, 1]
# >>> 2  [2, 2]
# >>> 2  [3, 3]
# >>> 2  [4, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, the problem arises from loc affecting values based on index matching.

Taking your example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1":[1,2,3], 
                   "col2":["a","b","c"], 
                   "col3":[None, np.array([2,4]), None]})
```

If you look at

```
mask = df.col3.isna()
mask
```

You actually have:

```
0     True
1    False
2     True
Name: col3, dtype: bool
```

So, although you are selecting only the rows with "True", the index still has a length of 3. Furthermore, your list `vals_to_impute` is not indexed, so Pandas does not know how to affect values.

A quick fix could be:

```
mask = df[df.col3.isna()].index
vals_to_impute = pd.Series([np.array([1, 2]), np.array([1, 4])], index=mask)
df.loc[mask,"col3"] = vals_to_impute
```

Note:

- There might be a more proper pandas way to do this.
- Using nd.arrays in a DataFrame column is rather uncommon to my knowledge, be aware you might encounter other problems later.